# How could I recognise a wallet is someone's Exchange wallet?

Tags: solscan, explorers, exchanges

I am developing a Solana transaction explorer and I want to be able to recognise a wallet as a Binance deposit wallet.

The current way I have found to do this is to check if a wallet sends money directly to a binance address, but I have only found 2 binance deposit addresses (Named Binance 1 and Binance 2 on solscan). Is there a way to check this without knowing an exchange's wallet addresses beforehand? As I would like to do this for other exchanges.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the blockchain, an exchange wallet is like any other wallet. Exchanges can choose how to manage their funds and users' wallets in any way. Your best bet is to go through exchange by exchange and figure out their deposit addresses.

Comment: got it, there's got to be discord servers for developers where they list known exchange addresses though. I will look for some and if not then ye I'll go through each exchange manually. ty!